# Can not update docker on windows

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, docker

Trying to install a new version on Docker on my Windows 10 PC but it fails systematically as there is a `Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin` directory on which even as administrator I have no rights.

Is there a way to force deletion of this folder?

Comment: Take ownership of the folder, backup it's contents, then delete the folder.  How you take ownership of a folder is well documented,  Several questions exist at Superuser that explain in detail how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to take ownership of this bin directory, following several links. But I figured out from one of the answers that a reboot might do the trick.

Post a reboot, I was able to remove the bin directory and install docker again with no issue.

Comment: i had the same issue. it worked on the second reboot. no idea.